# Excel Match function with concatenated value

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2010, worksheet-function

I am somewhat new to writing large, complicated formulas with excel.  I took over a report from someone about 7 months ago and it seems that every week I find issues with what was written with his formulas.

This week I am having issues with a match formula.  We have a report we run for a big hardware store and they report based on weeks.  This last week was 201501 (2015, week 1.)  Last week was 201452 (2014, week 52.)

To look at 4 week sales averages, my predecessor setup 4 numbers that would change every week based on the week you type in one of the column headings.  So, when I type 201452,

```
#1 is 201449
#2 is 201450
#3 is 201451
#4 is 201452
```

He feeds those into a match function.

I found this week that 201501 does not correctly display the weeks.  I got

```
Results   Formula Used
201501    =D1 (The cell where you type the Store's week)
201500    =IF(M1=201301,201252,IF(M1=201401,201352,M1-1))
201499    =IF(L1=201301,201252,IF(L1=201401,201352,L1-1))
201498    =IF(K1=201301,201252,IF(K1=201401,201352,K1-1))
```

I changed those formulas

```
Results   New Formula
201501    =D1
201452    =IF(RIGHT(M1,2) = "01",(LEFT(M1,4) - 1)&"52",M1-1)
201451    =IF(RIGHT(L1,2) = "01",(LEFT(L1,4) - 1)&"52",L1-1)
201450    =IF(RIGHT(K1,2) = "01",(LEFT(K1,4) - 1)&"52",K1-1)
```

However, the match formulas he has setup throughout the workbook have not been fixed.  They are still displaying "#N/A."  One such formula is

```
=INDEX(N5:DZ5,1,MATCH(Data!$L$1,$N$1:$ED$1,0))
```

This formula basically looks at the column headers, and if it sees that the column header matches the week I've typed, will display the value within that range.

Basically, any formula that's being fed the 201452 value is returning "#N/A".  The other numbers miraculously display data.

I've already tried converting all of my data in the affected rows to "General" format type.  I've tried checking to see if I have spaces before or after in all of my formulas and column headers, but am still having no luck.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

After trying and trying and trying, I found that Excel does not like the concatenation.  Trim does not help, Text does not help, Concatenate of course did not work.

I ended up realizing I could simply write
`=IF(RIGHT(M1,2) = "01",M1-49,M1-1)`

This makes it so that in the instance where the number to the right of it is the first week, subtract 49 days and produce 52 instead of 00.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here, but it could be that your formulas are presenting the Year/Week combo as a number, where the Match formula is looking for text (for Excel's purpose, it doesn't recognize them as the same).

You can get around this, by wrapping your formulas above with the text formula

So you'd have the following:

```
Results   New Formula
201501    =TEXT(D1,"0")
201452    =TEXT(IF(RIGHT(M1,2) = "01",(LEFT(M1,4) - 1)&"52",M1-1),"0")
201451    =TEXT(IF(RIGHT(L1,2) = "01",(LEFT(L1,4) - 1)&"52",L1-1),"0")
201450    =TEXT(IF(RIGHT(K1,2) = "01",(LEFT(K1,4) - 1)&"52",K1-1),"0")
```

Comment: * **Sigh** * Thanks for editing my initial answer.  I've tried the Text conversion, but that sadly causes even more formulas to display "#N/A."  I can plug any # into the match and get it to work.  Something about the 201452 # is way off, because the other three numbers work when plugged in, just not with the =Text() function.

Comment: Oddly, when I change the week to 201502, the formula that displays 201452 becomes the formula that is incorrect.  Obviously, something is wrong with my IF formula when true, but what the issue is is unbeknownst to me :/

Comment: what happens when you step through the formula?

Comment: I found a simple solution to my question and have posted that.  I did try stepping through earlier and was not able to find anything helpful. `=INDEX(N5:DZ5,1,MATCH(Data!$L$1,$N$1:$ED$1,0))` then `=IF(RIGHT(M1,2) = "01",(LEFT(M1,4) - 1)&"52",M1-1)` then `D1` then `201501` . I think I was just overthinking the problem and was not realizing how simple the solution really was.